# Is there a way to go to the project containing the file open in the editor in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a solution with lots of projects. Is there a way to select the project in the solution explorer containing the file currently opened in the editor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, go to `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions` and check the  `Track Active Item in Solution Explorer` checkbox